# Which design patterns to apply for item edit, create, etc

Tags: design-patterns, crud

Currently I am refactoring one of my projects and it has functionality like an ad management ( ad creation, editing, deletion, etc ).

At this time the code is very messy, full of `if` statements, by which it is determining whether an ad is being created, edited and so on.

**The target:**

I want to re-factor the code, implement some design patterns and make code more readable.

**Details:**

The main question is how to deal with ad data fields:

Single Ad has own and common fields like an: *title, description, create date, update date, category, and etc*.
Also ad has "dynamic fields", i.e.: photos, dynamic fields by category, etc.

**Question:**

Which design pattern(s) to use for these dynamic "fields"?

Answer (score 0):

Why not start looking at the [Active Record](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) pattern and see if that meets your needs. If not, start looking higher up the complexity hierarchy, [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), etc.